# How to configure multiple NIC cards on ubuntu server 14.04 LTS and connect to router?

Tags: linux, proxy, firewall, router, ubuntu-server

I have an HP hard Server on which I installed Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS. The server has two ethernet cards.
I installed Squid proxy server and I am using iptables as a firewall on my ubuntu server.
Now I want to place my Server between the router and the switch. This is because I want everyone to go through the proxy server to filter some web sites.

I am facing some difficulties in the configuration of the two NIC cards on the ubuntu server.
It has two interfaces em1 and em2 to which I want to assign static IP addressses. This is what I have configured so far:

### The primary network interface

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.1.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.2
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

### The secondary network interface

```
auto em2
iface em2 inet static
address 192.168.1.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

I read some posts that said there shouldn't be a gateway entry in the second interface so the OS knows which interface to use.

My current network architecture is the following:

FSI --> my CISCO Router (192.168.1.1) --> my Ubuntu server (containing two NIC cards and running squid proxy and iptables firewall) --> my switch --> some laptops

The problem is laptops are unable to connect to the internet. I don't understand why. I disabled the firewall and the proxy but I still cannot connect.

Should I configure some routing rules between the two NIC cards or should I use the FORWARD chain of iptables? How can I solve this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: A lot to configure, including enabling forwarding, configuring iptables, installing a DHCP server (e.g. dnsmasq) if needed. Refer to this article: [Setting up an Ubuntu Wired/Wireless Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am reading it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two network interfaces need to be on different networks/subnet IP ranges. So, for example, I had `em1` on `192.168.1.2` and `em2` on `192.168.2.1`. Then I connected `em1` to the **router** and `em2` to the **switch**. I gave my laptops `192.168.2.xxx` IPs (other than the server's IP). Ideally, I set up a DHCP server on the Ubuntu server to hand out IPs to the clients, so I don't have to set them up manually.

Then I set up forwarding in the `iptables` rules using the `FORWARD` chain (unless I want to enforce that ALL traffic goes through the proxy, then I just set up the proxy).

The working configuration is as follows:

```
# The primary network interface
auto em1  
iface em1 inet static  
address 192.168.1.2  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
gateway 192.168.1.2  
network 192.168.1.0  
broadcast 192.168.1.255  


# The secondary network interface
auto em2
iface em2 inet static
address 192.168.2.1
network 192.168.2.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

and iptables as follows:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i em1 -o em2 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i em2 -o em1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
```

When configuring laptops, keep in mind that the gateway should be the server's IP: `192.168.2.1`, which is my server's IP.